# Formula works when typed, fails when imported

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a large csv that I am hoping to import into Google Sheets. Each row has a column with "
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A, A2)<=1" (the A2 changes based on the row it is, incrementing each time) that when imported throws a "Formula Parse Error", but if I hand edit that formula at all or type it myself it will work fine.

Is there something I can do to allow that function to be imported?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding something like the below formula in cell B2? This would only require 1 formula, but is a lot slower if there's more than 5k rows.

```
 =arrayformula(
if($A$2:$A="","",
COUNTIF($A$2:$A, A2:A)<=1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `;` instead of `,` :

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A; A2)<=1
```

or go to **`File > Settings > Locale`** and change it to english-based country